# R import excel with readxl package bug

Tags: r, excel, import, readxl

The problem which I faced: all huge numbers during process of import by readxl converting to "-2147483648". Examples of my "huge" numbers: 45000000000,55000000000. Converting to text in Excel didn't help, defining col_types as "text" either. Is any way to workaround it?

Comment: Show your code and output

Comment: Look into the package `readr` which has `readlines` or `read_tsv(..., col_types="c")`

Comment: code is simple. `cols <- read_excel(files, sheet = 1,col_names = FALSE )` . output in examples above. I just found partial solution:`col_types="numeric" ` give a correct output for huge numbers, but I can't  specify col_types for all colums, as number of columns is really big.

Comment: do you get the correct numbers with `col_types="list"` ?